# 'For loop' not outputting correctly (always using 'else' of argument)

Tags: python, for-loop, if-statement

I am creating a program to recreate the Pokedex from the Pokemon TV/Anime series (to train myself how to use Classes and the tkinter module) but the search loop outputs the wrong part of the 'for' loop even when the user input is within the database for the Pokedex.
Meaning, if the user's input is 7, then it should use the 'display' function from within the class to show entry 7 in the Pokedex (which would be Squirtle); like this: "This is a Squirtle. The Squirtle is 0.5m tall and weighs 9kg. The Squirtle is a Water type and is weak against Grass & Electric." but it doesn't do that, it just always prints the error message of "Pokemon not found on Pokedex".

The search function works if I remove the second half of the 'for' loop, which is meant to throw back an error message and allow the user to input another number for the search. But when I add the error message part of the loop back in, it just always displays the error message even when it should work.

Here's the code:

```py
class Pokemon:
    'Class base for all Pokemon inside the Pokedex'

    def __init__(self, pkdx_num, name, height, weight, type, weaknesses):
        self.pkdx_num = pkdx_num
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight
        self.type = type
        self.weaknesses = weaknesses

    def display(self):
        print(f"This is a {self.name}.")
        print(f"The {self.name} is {self.height} tall and weighs {self.weight}.")
        print(f"The {self.name} is a {self.type} type and is weak against {self.weaknesses}.")

#Pokedex Database
pkdx_1 = Pokemon(1, "Bulbasaur", "0.7m", "6.9kg", "Grass" "Poison", "Fire, Psychic, Flying & Ice")
pkdx_2 = Pokemon(2, "Ivysaur", "1m", "13kg", "Grass" "Poison", "Fire" "Psychic" "Flying" "Ice")
pkdx_3 = Pokemon(3, "Venusaur", "2m", "100kg", "Grass" "Poison", "Fire" "Psychic" "Flying" "Ice")
pkdx_4 = Pokemon(4, "Charmander", "0.6m", "8.5kg", "Fire", "Water, Ground & Rock")
pkdx_5 = Pokemon(5, "Charmeleon", "1.1m", "19kg", "Fire", "Water, Ground & Rock")
pkdx_6 = Pokemon(6, "Charizard", "1.7m", "90.5kg", "Fire", "Water, Ground & Rock")
pkdx_7 = Pokemon(7, "Squirtle", "0.5m", "9kg", "Water", "Grass & Electric")
pkdx_8 = Pokemon(8, "Wartortle", "1m", "22.5kg", "Water", "Grass & Electric")
pkdx_9 = Pokemon(9, "Blastoise", "1.6m", "85.5kg", "Water", "Grass & Electric")
pokedex = [pkdx_1, pkdx_2, pkdx_3, pkdx_4, pkdx_5, pkdx_6, pkdx_7, pkdx_8, pkdx_9]


#-Pokedex Search Debugging
#Pokemon.display(pkdx_7)
#pkdx_search = "7" #-Pokedex Search Function Debugger/Tester

pkdx_search = int(input("What Number in the Pokedex do you want to search? "))

for Pokemon in pokedex:
    if Pokemon.pkdx_num == pkdx_search:
        Pokemon.display()
        break
    else:
        print("Pokemon not found on Pokedex")
        break
```

Comment: could you try `for p in pokedex`, as there is a name collision between `Pokemon` (the class) and `Pokemon` (the iterator)

Comment: To be honest this looks like a job for a dictionary.

Answer (score 0):

It's not good to overwrite existing values/builtins such as `type` and `Pokemon` in your code. Please review that. Also your `else` has a `break` in it which stops after the first not found Pokemon. Remove the `break` and that should fix it.

Also using a `dict` instead of a list would be a way better data structure to use here as you could just do:

```
pokedex = {p.pkdx_num: p for p in [pkdx_1, pkdx_2, pkdx_3, pkdx_4, pkdx_5, pkdx_6, pkdx_7, pkdx_8, pkdx_9]}

pkdx_search = int(input("What Number in the Pokedex do you want to search? "))

found_pokemon = pokedex.get(pxdx_search)

if found_pokemon:
    found_pokemon.display()
else:
    print("Pokemon not found on Pokedex")
```

Comment: When I remove the second break, the loop seems to run through every class entry. So if I input 7, then it prints "Pokemon not found" 6 times and then runs the 'display' class function?
Also I've now changed the 'type' in the class to be 'element_type' since I assume that's what you meant by overwriting values?

Answer (score 0):

for pokemon in pokedex starts in pokemon 1 bulbasur. As pokemon 1 bulbasor is not 7 (the input number) the else is executed. Prints that there is no pokemon, an exits the loop.

What you want is:

```
poke_match = [pokemon for pokemon in pokedex if pokemon.pkdx_num==input]
#This are all pokemons that matched the search
if poke_match == []:
     #No pokemon found
else:
     poke_match[0] #is the pokemon match
```

Answer (score 0):

This task looks better suited to a dictionary, holding their position in the pokedex against each pokemon doesn't seem right, as that is not an attribute of the pokemon themselves.

```py
pokedex={}    
pokedex[1] = Pokemon("Bulbasaur", "0.7m", "6.9kg", "Grass" "Poison", "Fire, Psychic, Flying & Ice")
pokedex[2] = Pokemon("Ivysaur", "1m", "13kg", "Grass" "Poison", "Fire" "Psychic" "Flying" "Ice")
pokedex[3] = Pokemon("Venusaur", "2m", "100kg", "Grass" "Poison", "Fire" "Psychic" "Flying" "Ice")
pokedex[4] = Pokemon("Charmander", "0.6m", "8.5kg", "Fire", "Water, Ground & Rock")
pokedex[5] = Pokemon("Charmeleon", "1.1m", "19kg", "Fire", "Water, Ground & Rock")
pokedex[6] = Pokemon("Charizard", "1.7m", "90.5kg", "Fire", "Water, Ground & Rock")
pokedex[7] = Pokemon("Squirtle", "0.5m", "9kg", "Water", "Grass & Electric")
pokedex[8] = Pokemon("Wartortle", "1m", "22.5kg", "Water", "Grass & Electric")
pokedex[9] = Pokemon("Blastoise", "1.6m", "85.5kg", "Water", "Grass & Electric")

pkdx_search = int(input("What Number in the Pokedex do you want to search? "))

if pkdx_search in pokedex:
    pokedex[pkdx_search].display()
```

Comment: Will give this a go. Still new and learning how all this stuff mixes together into usable programs. I want to later on add functions for sorting/searching from other attributes, like finding every 'Grass' type in the Pokedex or all the pokemon that are under 1m tall, which I presume i'd be able to do building it with a dictionary?

Comment: Giving the Pokemons an 'attributes' dictionary would be one option {"Name":"Bulbasaur","height":0.4, etc.}  then you can lookup on the attribute dynamically.